# How to hold index of object inside of array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to code "blockchain" visual implementation in React. I want to hold somehow inside array of objects(that are my blocks) index of each object. I can't figure out how to do it.

```
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      blocks: [{
        hash: calculateHash(1),
        timestamp: timeStamp(),
        dataOfBlock: 'Genesis Block',
        nounce: 607,
        index: 0
      }]
    }
  };

    addBlock = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      this.setState({
      blocks: [...this.state.blocks, {
        hash: 'cos',
        timestamp: timeStamp(),      
        dataOfBlock: this.state.value,
        nounce: '',
        index: 1 // here's the problem
      }]
    })
    }
```

My code mimics what i want to accomplish where the comment is. I want to constantly add +1 to my index with each block.

Comment: if your always adding to the end of the array, you can make index this.state.blocks.length because the length of the prev array will be the index point of the new block

Comment: `index: this.state.blocks.length+1`, suggestion: use `prevState` instead of `this.state` inside `setState`.

Comment: my god, that was so easy, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `length` as index of new object when adding new object
**Note**: `this.state.blocks.length` will the next index because index start from `0`

```
blocks: [...this.state.blocks, {
        hash: 'cos',
        timestamp: timeStamp(),      
        dataOfBlock: this.state.value,
        nounce: '',
        index: this.state.blocks.length
      }]
```